# Code Coverage for Android Library Project while using Robolectric

Tags: android, ant, code-coverage, robolectric, eclemma

I have an android library project. We are using Robolectric to run the unit tests. Unit Tests are working fine from the IDE as well as Ant build.xml file. I am able to get the code coverage using the eclEmma plugin in Eclipse. But I am facing problems while getting coverage report from ant build. Tried using Jacoco for coverage report generation but getting 0% code coverage in spite of the fact that all tests are passing and code coverage from the plugin is 85%.
Could anybody suggest what would be right framework for getting code coverage for unit tests while I am using Robolectric for unit tests and ant for build purposes.

Comment: I think it is not a framework question but coverage configuration. We use jacoco code coverage throug gradle plugin

Comment: Thanks @EugenMartynov. I have updated the answer to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a problem with configuration only. I changed the configuration and updated my build.xml . Now it works like a charm. I am able to get code coverage easily through Jacoco